# Difference between NSLog and NSLogv

Tags: objective-c, swift, nslog

Can anyone explain the difference between NSLog and NSLogv? I know `NSLog` is used to print data in the console.  But what is `NSLogv`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose you want to write a function *similar to* NSLog, but which also saves the message to an array in addition to logging it. How would you implement this?

If you write a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) `void MySpecialLog(NSString *format, ...)`, someone can call your function just like NSLog — `MySpecialLog(@"Hello %@!", name);` — but the only way to access the extra arguments beyond `format` is with [a `va_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list). There's no [splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) in C or Obj-C allowing you to pass them directly to NSLog inside the function.

NSLogv solves this problem by accepting all the additional arguments at once via a `va_list`. Its signature is `void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args)`. You can use it to **build your own** NSLog wrappers.

## Obj-C

```
void MySpecialLog(NSString *format, ...)
  NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1, 2)
    // The NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION attribute tells the compiler to treat the 1st argument like
    // a format string, with values starting from the 2nd argument. This way, you'll
    // get the proper warnings if format specifiers and arguments don't match.
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // Do something slightly more interesting than just passing format & args through...
    NSString *newFormat = [@"You've called MySpecialLog()! " stringByAppendingString:format];

    NSLogv(newFormat, args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

You can even use the same technique to wrap NSLog with an Obj-C method. (And since `-[NSString initWithFormat:]` has a similar variant called `-initWithFormat:arguments:`, you can wrap it too.)

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1, 2)
{
    // Similarly to the above, we can pass all the arguments to -initWithFormat:arguments:.
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);

    // Why not both?
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

---

## Swift

In Swift, you can do this with a variadic function accepting `CVarArg...`:

```
func mySpecialLog(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...) {
    withVaList(args) {
        NSLogv("You've called mySpecialLog()! " + format, $0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be *"... if you didn't have NSLog, ..."* in the first line of your first code example?

Comment: @jtbandes: Exactly. You build a NSLog replacement *using* NSLogv, therefore *"if you didn't have NSLogv"* sounds misleading to me.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a suffix of `v` means that a function takes a `va_list` as an argument, instead of a variadic argument list.

This is the case for [`NSLog`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1395275-nslog?language=objc) and [`NSLogv`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1395074-nslogv?language=objc):

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...);

void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args);
```

This is useful in certain very specific situations where you need to "wrap" a function that takes variadic arguments. If you need it, you'll know. Otherwise, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Please explain "you need to "wrap" a function that takes variadic arguments"

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` is a [varadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which means it takes a variable number of arguments.  But sometimes, programmers will want to implement their own varadic wrapper function which does something else before calling `NSLog`.

If `NSLog` was the only function, that wouldn't be possible because you can't pass a set of varadic arguments (aka a `va_list`) to another varadic function.

That's why `NSLogv` exists separately from `NSLog`, which is just a wrapper that accepts a variable number of arguments and passes them to `NSLogv`.