# What is the D/B NSLog and NSLogv ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I follow official Apple's documentation but i don't seem any relevant answer to my question.

```
NSLog VS NSLogv
```

Comment: Is it same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968210/difference-between-nslog-and-nslogv

Answer (score 0):

no difference , NSLog called NSLogv with parameter . So if you user NSLog with some parameter , NSLog Re-called NSLogv Function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variant of NSLog that accepts a va_list called NSLogv:

```
- (void) log:(NSString *)text, ... {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, text);
  NSLogv(text, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

The only way to forward the actual ... (not the va_list) is to use a macro. For example:

```
#define MyLog(f, ...) { \
NSLog(f, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
[someObject doSomething:f, ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
}
```