# Why the procedure NSLogv is commented in iOSapi.Foundation?

Tags: delphi

in iOSapi.Foundation.pas we have this row :

```
//procedure NSLogv(format: PNSString; args: va_list); cdecl; external libFoundation name _PU + 'NSLogv';
```

Why it is commented / deactivated ? This procedure is defined like this in the header :

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
```

When i try to uncomment it, i have an error: va_list not defined. If i not make any mistake, va_list is just a pointer ?

After how to call this function ? NB: i need to call this exact function, not any other log function ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLogv` exists when you need to wrap a call to `NSLog` with your own variadic function. But since you can't *write* a variadic function in Delphi, that scenario cannot apply.

Call `NSLog` instead. This is an externally defined variadic function. Although Delphi cannot be used to write such things, it is capable of consuming them.

For more details refer to this topic: [Difference between NSLog and NSLogv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968210/difference-between-nslog-and-nslogv).

Further reading:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#External_Declarations

Comment: thanks David, so you mean we can not translate / call in delphi any ios function with va_list ? NSLogv was taken as example, because i need to call this function in a 3rd library: `void FIRCrashLogv(NSString *format, va_list ap);` that is similar to NSLogv ... is their any workaround ?

Comment: Call [`FIRCrashLog`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecrash/api/reference/Functions#/c:FIRCrashLog.h@F@FIRCrashLog) instead

Comment: Thanks david, but FIRCrashLog is defined like this in the FIRCrashLog.h; `FOUNDATION_STATIC_INLINE NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1, 2)
void FIRCrashLog(NSString *format, ...) {...}` and it's seam i can not import it in delphi because miss the keyword `extern` ... only FIRCrashLogv have the keyword `extern` ... or their is a way to import in delphi such static inlined function ?

Comment: OK, then you are in trouble. I don't think that you can readily make a va_list in Delphi. No doube the body of `FIRCrashLog` includes the macros `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end`. But this is a different question now, isn't it? You asked about `NSLogv`. I do think I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: you are right! you answer well this question thanks ... i start a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843006/how-to-call-in-delphi-an-ios-variadic-function

Comment: Just a remark: i discover that delphi have the `varargs` parameters ... but don't find out how to use it ...

Comment: @loki you can't use `varargs` to call `NSLogv` or `FIRCrashLogv`, it would be used for calling `NSLog` or `FIRCrashLog` instead. `varargs` is Delphi's implementation of C's `...` syntax in a variadic parameter list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : quite strangely it's work with varargs ! i try on FIRCrashLogv with declaring the procedure like this : `procedure FIRCrashLogv(format: PNSString); cdecl; varargs; external 'FirebaseCrash' name 'FIRCrashLogv';` and it's work !

Comment: It won't be working. You might fluke it if you have zero or one variadic args. But that's it.

Comment: @loki: It can't work that way. Calling a function with a `varargs` parameter list is different than calling a function with a `va_list` parameter. They are related, but the call stacks are very different.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : i believe you but i assure you it's work ! and if you look the source code of delphi, they also do the same for 2 functions : CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArguments and CFStringAppendFormatAndArguments

Comment: Either you believe us or you don't.

Comment: @loki: `varargs` is NOT compatible with `va_list` - period.  That is not what `varargs` is designed for, that is not how the compiler implements it.  If Embarcadero declared `va_list` functions using `varargs` instead, then they did the wrong thing, and that is a ticking time bomb waiting to crash someone's code. Try it with a function that takes a whole bunch of variadic values as input, not just 1 or 2, and see what happens. Best case, you get garbage output. Worse case, it corrupts memory and/or crashes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm so i m just lucky that it's work, maybe because i don't pass any arguments to varargs. And delphi (as often) translate badly some ios function. Real  question, is their any way in delphi to use va_list ?

Comment: @loki I already said exactly that. Of course if you don't pass any arguments, then it will appear to work.