# How to call in delphi an iOS function with a va_list parameter?

Tags: delphi

I need to call this function from the firebase library:

```
FOUNDATION_EXTERN NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1, 0)
void FIRCrashLogv(NSString *format, va_list ap);
```

I learnt at my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837881/) that Delphi does not offer a way to create `va_list` arguments and instead expects me to call the variadic function `FIRCrashLog`. Unfortunately, for this library, `FIRCrashLog` is not exported and is instead an inline function. This means that I cannot import it using an `external` declaration using `varargs`.

Is it possible to call the `FIRCrashLogv` variant from Delphi, and if so how can I do it?

Comment: I re-wrote your question. I hope that is alright. Regarding your version, `varargs` is for declaring an external variadic function, but that's not relevant here. That would be how you would declare and import `FIRCrashLog` were it exported. So I removed that.

Comment: thanks David look alright ...